# HAProxy: the ACL can't detect the client hostname

Tags: haproxy

I configured an HAProxy server that should detect if the request comes from `server.company.cxx` and forward the request to the server on 10.0.x.x. If the request does not fulfill this condition, it will forward the request to a default web server on localhost.

So, I'm using this configuration:

```
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    # [...]

frontend public
    bind :8080

    acl is_company_server hdr(host) -i server.company.cxx

    use_backend company_www if is_company_server
    default_backend default

backend company_www
    timeout server 60s
    server www_server 10.x.x.x:8080

backend default
    timeout server 2s
    server default 127.0.0.1:80
```

I tried to access to `http://server.mycompany.cxx:8080`, but every request ends on default backend. It's like the `acl` are not working.

I activated the logging service, but I only see this:

```
Jul  3 19:26:41 localhost haproxy[11070]: 70.x.x.x:60819 [03/Jul/2016:19:26:41.563] public default/default 0/0/0/0/0 304 174 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

**How can I know why HAProxy selected the backend "default" and the ACL failed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was very simple: the HAProxy server was listening on the port 8080. So, the URL was `http://server.company.cxx:8080/`. Therefore, the host name was `server.company.cxx:8080`, including the port number as part of the hostname.

This fixed the problem:

```
frontend public
    bind :8080

    acl is_company_server hdr(host) -i server.company.cxx:8080
```

Or, it could be solved with this:

```
frontend public
    bind :8080

    acl is_company_server hdr_dom(host) -i server.company.cxx
```